# Need to click twice to update the state in react hooks. toggle button

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

i need to click two times on the button to update the state.
i have two buttons. when i toggles between the buttons the text should change.

I found some questions related to this but did not worked for me.

please find Below code.

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import './SectionConnect.css';

const SectionConnect = () => {

const [activeButton, setActiveButton] = useState("company");

function toggleButton() {
  setActiveButton(activeButton==="company" ? "individual" : "company");

}



  return (
    <div className="connect-container">
      <div className="connect-wrapper">
        <h2>How it works</h2>
        
    {activeButton==="company"?<p>
          We help your employees maximise potential through a bespoke, science-backed wellbeing platform. 
        </p>:<p>
          We connect you with the very best practitioners and most effective
          methods to achieve optimal health.
        </p>}

        
        <div className="connect-btn">
          <NavLink
            to="/"
            exact
            activeClassName="active-btn"
            className="disable-btn"
           onClick={toggleButton}
          >
            For companies
          </NavLink>
          <NavLink
            to="/forIndividuals"
            exact
            activeClassName="active-btn"
            className="disable-btn"
            onClick={toggleButton}
          >
            For individuals
          </NavLink>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SectionConnect
```

Not able to understand where i am going wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you add the code to the online code snippet so that i can check the result?

Comment: Why are you using navlink ? its used for navigation so probably first click its navigating

Answer (score 0):

on toggleButton call like this `onClick={()=> toggleButton()}`

Comment: Yes, First Click it's navigation why you use navlink?

Comment: Using Navlink to go to some other page, can i use Navlink for both usage, 1. onClick and to goto some other page as well